# How to split the string in vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a string like

```
      string1= "sample thing(model)"
```

I need to get the string inside the parantheses i.e model. And i'm using the below code but not working. which method do i need to use.

```
      vString1 = Split(string1, "(",2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know it's always gonna be the parens, I would use the Instr() method.  Combined with the Mid() function, it would look like this:

```
'Find the location of the open parens
X = Instr (string1, "(")
'Find the location of the close parens
Y = Instr (string1, ")")

'Use the Mid function to find the string located inside the parens
MyString = Mid(string1, X, Y)
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. I'm getting like **(model)** i used Replace fn to replace ( , ) with ""

Comment: Try **MyString = Mid(string1, X+1, Y-1)** to offset the parens, then.  Don't forget, you're going to need to include the asterisk ("*") in a LIKE clause or it won't find any matches.